# Is there anyway to declare a TYPE without a Property in Oracle 10gR2

Tags: oracle, inheritance, types

I want to create a base object that has only methods. The object would be `QUEUABLE_OBJECT_TYPE` and it will have an `ENQUEUE` method(s). The Payload of these messages (properties) would be added by subtyping this object.

I get an error that makes it sound like you cannot:

> PLS-00589: no attributes found in object type "QUEUABLE_OBJECT_TYPE"

Does anyone know a way around this error? Or is it possible in the subtypes to hide this property of the supertype?

Either would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything I've read suggests it is not possible to create a type without any attributes. Nor is it possible to hide a dummy attribute in a subtype. You may simply have to have an attribute in the master type, and utilise it - e.g. by making it identify the version of the type.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does provide some generic types, [see documentation for details](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjadv.htm#sthref948)

Comment: You're not understanding the question. It needs to be something I can use when I do a CREATE TYPE. The answer from Jamie is probably completely correct. I'm just waiting to see if someone rescues me with contradictory info.

Comment: I did understand the question,I was just suggesting a feature that may provide you with an alternative approach, as I agree with Jamie and don't think what you are asking above is possible.